# Cakephp rewrite rule

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting, rule, cakephp-routing

I have url Microsites/index.
With action index I want to pass parameter like 1001.So, crated rule for it as given below:

Router::redirect('/Microsites', array('controller' => 'Microsites', 'action' => 'index',1001));

It working fine & shows url in addressbar like: 
/Microsites/index/101

But,
I want to show url like : /Microsites/index

Most welcome for suggestions....

Comment: First param of ::redirect is for How Your link must look.

Answer (score 1):

How do you build your link? The array you pass to the Html::link method must be the array you declared in your route so that it matches and the router genrates the correct URL string based on the give array data.

```
$this->Html->link('Microsites', array('controller' => 'Microsites', 'action' => 'index',1001));
```

Should do it.